# Create sliding windows for each data column

Tags: r

1. I have a dataframe with some variables.
2. I want to turn each variable into a sliding window.
3. And then connect all the sliding windows into a matrix or dataframe

###### 1)

```
df <- data.frame(A=paste0("a",1:10),
                 B=paste0("b",1:10),
                 C=paste0("c",1:10))
```

###### 2)

```
roll_window <- function(x,n=3) embed(x,dim = n)[,n:1]
list_of_windows <- lapply(df, roll_window)
```

###### 3)

```
 do.call(cbind, list_of_windows)
```

`do.call(cbind, list_of_windows)` is expected result

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] 
[1,] "a1" "a2" "a3"  "b1" "b2" "b3"  "c1" "c2" "c3" 
[2,] "a2" "a3" "a4"  "b2" "b3" "b4"  "c2" "c3" "c4" 
[3,] "a3" "a4" "a5"  "b3" "b4" "b5"  "c3" "c4" "c5" 
[4,] "a4" "a5" "a6"  "b4" "b5" "b6"  "c4" "c5" "c6" 
[5,] "a5" "a6" "a7"  "b5" "b6" "b7"  "c5" "c6" "c7" 
[6,] "a6" "a7" "a8"  "b6" "b7" "b8"  "c6" "c7" "c8" 
[7,] "a7" "a8" "a9"  "b7" "b8" "b9"  "c7" "c8" "c9" 
[8,] "a8" "a9" "a10" "b8" "b9" "b10" "c8" "c9" "c10"
```

The question is: Is it possible to do points `2` and `3` more elegantly and with less code?

Comment: You might want to look at the [slider package](https://slider.r-lib.org/articles/slider.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(df, 3, c)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] 
[1,] "a1" "a2" "a3"  "b1" "b2" "b3"  "c1" "c2" "c3" 
[2,] "a2" "a3" "a4"  "b2" "b3" "b4"  "c2" "c3" "c4" 
[3,] "a3" "a4" "a5"  "b3" "b4" "b5"  "c3" "c4" "c5" 
[4,] "a4" "a5" "a6"  "b4" "b5" "b6"  "c4" "c5" "c6" 
[5,] "a5" "a6" "a7"  "b5" "b6" "b7"  "c5" "c6" "c7" 
[6,] "a6" "a7" "a8"  "b6" "b7" "b8"  "c6" "c7" "c8" 
[7,] "a7" "a8" "a9"  "b7" "b8" "b9"  "c7" "c8" "c9" 
[8,] "a8" "a9" "a10" "b8" "b9" "b10" "c8" "c9" "c10"
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R use `embed`:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, \(x)embed(x,3)[,3:1]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] 
[1,] "a1" "a2" "a3"  "b1" "b2" "b3"  "c1" "c2" "c3" 
[2,] "a2" "a3" "a4"  "b2" "b3" "b4"  "c2" "c3" "c4" 
[3,] "a3" "a4" "a5"  "b3" "b4" "b5"  "c3" "c4" "c5" 
[4,] "a4" "a5" "a6"  "b4" "b5" "b6"  "c4" "c5" "c6" 
[5,] "a5" "a6" "a7"  "b5" "b6" "b7"  "c5" "c6" "c7" 
[6,] "a6" "a7" "a8"  "b6" "b7" "b8"  "c6" "c7" "c8" 
[7,] "a7" "a8" "a9"  "b7" "b8" "b9"  "c7" "c8" "c9" 
[8,] "a8" "a9" "a10" "b8" "b9" "b10" "c8" "c9" "c10"
```

If you do not care about the column arrangements, s you can always subset accordingly, then use:

```
n <- 3
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, embed, n))
```

---

To subset accordingle, use the index:

```
(seq(n*ncol(df)-1,0) %% n + 1) * rep(seq(ncol(df),each = n)
```

Comment: you just rewrote my code :)
And the last lines of code either work incorrectly or don’t work at all